# Yahoo OAuth implementation has no way to work offline

Tags: oauth, yahoo-oauth

I need to download my Delicious bookmarks to a non-web application without constant user interaction. I'm using Delicious's V2 API (using oAuth) but the problem is it seems their access tokens expire after one hour.

I don't have any issues with redirecting the user to Yahoo for a one time authorization, but what is described here (http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-refreshaccesstoken.html) means I would have to refresh my access tokens all the time before they expire when the user is away.

Is this really the way they've done their oAuth implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to refresh the access token when they come to use the application again, not while they're away. You can pass the previously expired token and get a new one in return.

Comment: The use case involves reading the posts from Yahoo in the background while the user is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a problem?  You should only need to make an additional server-side call to refresh the access token if it expires (as long as the authorization itself has not expired, which should last longer, and would need user interaction when it expired).